# jpg image not getting rendered in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, xhtml

I have one jpg image which is getting rendered in FF but not in IE6.

```
 <img src="Image/warn.jpg" alt="aimage" />
```

Path is correct as this is working on FF. any clue?

Comment: Are you sure the path is correct and Firefox didn’t use a cached representation?

Comment: Can you post a link to the image, that way we can see if it's a problem with the image itself.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the file name would be server-side so it shouldn't matter if you use IE6 or FF or Chrome or Opera. IE6 is probably able to find the file, just not to display it.

With JPG files, there is an option to store it as progressive or as a lossless JPG file. It's likely that this image happens to be in a file format that IE6 just doesn't understand. The lossless JPG format is slightly newer than IE6, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Is it really a jpg image, isn't it e.g. PNG with wrong suffix? Have you tried to use directly the url of the jpeg image?

Answer (score 0):

try to right-click the image and then click properties, in the properties click the security tab, and in the security tab I think you should just add user group.